Incompatibility between AES and Hybrid Homomorphic Encryption
I read in this paper here
that symmetric ciphers like AES is not a good choice for Hybrid Homomorphic Encryption due to large multiplicative depth. I want to understand more about this statement. How is the multiplicative depth of AES computed? And why is it not compatible for this reason?
I tried looking into other papers but every other paper says the same line without any details into it. I cannot understand how you compute multiplicative depth of AES or symmetric ciphers

This is likely a very good question for crypto.stackexchange.com because it's about the theory and mechanics of cryptography. Here, it's off-topic because it's not about programming. Best of luck with your search.
